# Combobox DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 RadioButton controls along with 2 ComboBox controls.

The user has the option of selecting Option 1 or Option 2.  If Option 1 is selected I want the combobox to be disabled and if there was a selected value in the combobox I want it to be cleared.  And vice versa if Option 2 is selected.

```
<RadioButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Checked="rbOption1Checked" >
    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Option 1 (Optional):" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</RadioButton>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="cboOption1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsRegionSelected}"/>

<RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Checked="rbOption2Checked">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Option 2 (Optional):" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</RadioButton>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="cboOption2" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsRegionSelected}" />
```

I'd like to know how this could be accomplished with a DataTrigger. I don't know where to start on this.  I've tried something like this but nothing happned.

```
<RadioButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Checked="rbOption2Checked">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Option 2 (Optional):" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</RadioButton>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="cboOption2" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsRegionSelected}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked,ElementName=cboOption1}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="ComboBox.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can definitely be done through a trigger.  I think the first problem that you're having, and it's a common one, is that you're setting a property directly on your control and then trying to override it in the `Style`; the direct setting is going to override the Style.  This may be why the `IsEnabled` property is never changing.

Here's the xaml for a `RadioButton` and a `ComboBox`, where the combo is only enabled and its selected item is only set when the corresponding button is checked

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radioButton1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Option 1 (Optional):" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</RadioButton>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="cboOption1" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedOption1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked,ElementName=radioButton1}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

What the `Style` is doing here is setting a default binding to the DataContext.  When `radioButton1` isn't checked, it's disabling the control and removing the binding; this does not change anything in the underlying *ViewModel*.  When the button is checked, the binding is going to be set again and your control will reflect whatever value was originally selected.